# Flatten array of observables return by switchMap() in pipe()

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a method `getFolders()` which returns a `Observable`.

```js
function getFolders() {

  const data = [
       {
          name: "Photos",
          files: of(2) // observable
       },
       {
          name: "Document",
          files: of(5) // observable
       },
       {
          name: "Videos",
          files: of(2) // observable
       }
  ];

  return of(data);

}
```

I need to get the **total files count** with is **9**  (`2+5+2`). I wrote a function to do the job by the following usage,

```js
getFileCount.subscribe( totalCount => console.log(totalCount) );

// expects to log 9
```

The implementation is,

```js
function getFileCount() {

   return getFolders()
            .pipe(
               switchMap( folderData => folderData.map( data => data.files ) ),
               // Above switchMap returns [ Observable, Observable, Observable ]
               // Now I need to complete all Observable and get flatten result like [2,5,2]

               mergeAll(),
               // I though the mergeAll will resolve all Observables and return the value
               
               switchMap( countArray => {

                   // expecting all values in a single array [2,5,2]
                   // but it executes for each value like
                   // 2
                   // 5
                   // 2

                   console.log(countArray);

                   return countArray.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
               })
            );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forkJoin` to wrap the observable array and remove `mergeAll()`, it'll execute each observable inside

```
switchMap( folderData => forkJoin(folderData.map( data => data.files ) )),
```

Comment: `@Fan Cheung` I tried exact same thing, But after adding `forkJoin` the next `switchMap` did not receive any data. Even the `console.log` in `subscribe()` also not triggering.

Comment: Actually, My bad. It was not `Observable` it was `AnonymousSubject`. Using `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin` solved the issue. Anyway, Your answer is correct for the given question. Thank you